# How to get only merged PRs from Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I'm currently trying to fetch only `PRs` that have been `merged` but after testing few different options, nothing works.

Latest version:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/pulls?state=closed+is:merged
```

Anything helps

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `pull` route doesn't have that option, or I didn't find it, but `issue` one works:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:<owner>/<repo-name>/+is:pr+merged:%3E=2022-10-09
```